Kubebuilder not generating deepCopyobject method
I am trying to create a kuberentes operator,
by following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNDjE9-2Bg4
I installed Kubebuilder and generated code using kubebuilder init
then used to create custom resource and controller
kubebuilder create api --group injector --version v1alpha1 --kind Injector

it is generating CR and controller, but this error is thrown:

cannot use &injector (value of type *v1alpha1.Injector) as client.Object value in argument to r.Client.Get: *v1alpha1.Injector does not implement client.Object (missing method DeepCopyObject)compilerInvalidIfaceAssign,

In generated code there is no method implemented like DeepCopyObject
/*
Copyright 2024 pruthviraj.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

package controller

import (
    "context"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"
    ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/log"

    "github.com/prha0922/operator/api/v1alpha1"
    injectorv1alpha1 "github.com/prha0922/operator/api/v1alpha1"
)

// InjectorReconciler reconciles a Injector object
type InjectorReconciler struct {
    client.Client
    Scheme *runtime.Scheme
}

// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=injector.com.prha.operator,resources=injectors,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=injector.com.prha.operator,resources=injectors/status,verbs=get;update;patch
// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=injector.com.prha.operator,resources=injectors/finalizers,verbs=update

// Reconcile is part of the main kubernetes reconciliation loop which aims to
// move the current state of the cluster closer to the desired state.
// TODO(user): Modify the Reconcile function to compare the state specified by
// the Injector object against the actual cluster state, and then
// perform operations to make the cluster state reflect the state specified by
// the user.
//
// For more details, check Reconcile and its Result here:
// - https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.18.2/pkg/reconcile
func (r *InjectorReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    _ = log.FromContext(ctx)

    var injector v1alpha1.Injector
    r.Client.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, &injector)
    // TODO(user): your logic here

    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
}

// SetupWithManager sets up the controller with the Manager.
func (r *InjectorReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&injectorv1alpha1.Injector{}).
        Complete(r)
}


What should i do here?
I am using all the latest version of go v1.22, kubebuilder v4
